# how to print a string more than one time in a assembly language using loop

Tags: assembly, x86

i am getting this error

**cndtlBranch.s:**

```
Assembler messages:
cndtlBranch.s:47: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
cndtlBranch.s:53: Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'
```

I am confused how to use push and pop instructions in assembly language.

**Here is my code:**

```
.data

String1:
.ascii "hai!\n"

String2:
.ascii "hai ra!\n"

String3:
.ascii "hai ra mama!\n"

.text

.globl _start

 _start:

    nop
    movl $10, %eax
    xorl %eax, %eax
    jz HelloWorld

    jumpIfZeroNot:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $String1, %ecx
    movl $5, %edx
    int $0x80
    jmp Exit

    jumpIfZero:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $String2, %ecx
    movl $8, %edx
    int $0x80
    jmp Exit

    Exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

    HelloWorld:
    movl $10, %ecx
    printTenTimes:
        push %ecx
        movl $4, %eax
        movl $1, %ebx
        leal String3, %ecx
        movl $13, %edx
        int $0x80
        pop %ecx
    loop printTenTimes
    jmp Exit
```

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit platform?  Those are assembly instructions for a 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Given the style you're using, I'm assuming you're using the GNU assembler. In that case, pass the option `--32` to `as` when compiling.

This will generate 32-bit code (which is the kind of code you're writing in) instead of 64-bit code (likely the kind of code you're generating by default).